# How to check the data in Apache IoTDB when transferring the results into JSONObject?

Tags: json, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I used the JDBC method to query data in Apache IoTDB, the sql statement is successfully executed, but when I tried to transfer the result into JSONObject, the response does not have the three fields: `max`, `min`, and `count`. Is this a bug or how can I successfully check the results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be a parsing problem. To be on the safe side, you may have to write your own code to parse your results. If you want your results in JSON, you can use the `rest` interface, which instructions are on the official website of Apache IoTDB.